# How to combine typedef'd struct with instance creation?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

So you can do this to create `c1` and `c2` as instances of `struct Complex`:

```
struct Complex {
    int real;
    int imag;
} c1, c2;
```

And you can do this to typedef the anonymous struct:

```
typedef struct { ... } Complex;
```

But is there any way to do both at once?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? is it because `c1` and `c2` are global variables?

Comment: I'm not sure why...I guess I'm just exploring the limits of the syntax right now so I understand what's possible.

Comment: Well if this was possible, it would be certainly useless, at least it's my point of view, and it might of course be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. `typedef`'s syntax is

```
typedef T type_ident;  // T is type specified by the declaration specifiers
```

This means that anything after `typedef T` will be a type name, not the instance of that type. So, in

```
typedef struct { ... } Complex, c1, c2;
```

`Complex`, `c1` and `c2` are all typedef name with the type `struct { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (PDF) says it's impossible, cause `typedef` is just one of the type specifiers. It's as if you had written `char int a;`.

Answer (score 0):

Storage-class specifiers (`typedef`, `static`, `extern` etc) always apply to the whole declaration. In the same way that one declaration cannot declare static and non-static variables, a `typedef` declaration can only define type definitions:

```
static int foo, bar; // Both foo and bar are static
typedef int c1, c2; // Both c1 and c2 are typedefs
```

Answer (score 0):

The first form declares a structure tag; the second declares a typedef. The main difference is that the second declaration is of a slightly more abstract type,if users don't necessarily know that it is a structure, and the keyword struct is not used when declaring instances of it...& Structures declared with tags, on the other hand, must be defined..So its not possible create c1 and c2 as instances of struct Complex....